# Google/StackExchange Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to make a navigation bar like that of Google (their new one) or StackExchange, where it's immediately at the top. It doesn't have to be persistent, and all I need on it are links, but how can I make it so that it stays immediately at the top like that? More importantly, how can I make it so that it always fills up the entire width of the screen (rather than having a defined width)?

Currently I have a simple inline list, but the width is defined.

I'd be willing to use new HTML5 techniques as well as CSS to any extent to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
<div id="topBar">
    This is content
</div>
```

css

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
#topBar{width:100%; text-align:center; background:#ccc; height:25px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Xpxhy/

So, you

1. place the `div` right after the opening `body` tag.
2. make sure there are no `margins` or `padding` on the body.
3. set the `width` to 100%
4. align the text in the center.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:fixed` in the toolbar style to keep it in a fixed position relative to the browser window (and not the browser window's elements).

```
#toolbar {
    position:fixed;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And define `width:100%` on the `nav` and a width of whatever you want on the `ul`. Set `margin:0 auto;` on the `ul`. To get it to stay at the top give `nav` `position:absolute;` and `top:0` properties.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a `div` with no width value set, outside of any width-restricted containers. It will automatically fill the entire width of the page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice navigation bar in the Twitter Bootstrap you could take a look at.
It is on Github at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation